# how to prohibit global planning through unknown area?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, All,

occasionally, I found my navigational stack (move_base) plans a route through unknown space.

how do I prohibit such behaviour?
I noticed there's a parameter

```
allow_unknown: false
```

for this purpose, But where should it be set?

Regards
Ray

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186804/how-to-prohibit-global-planning-through-unknown-area?/) by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ray,

You can **create a configuration file** named ***base_global_planner_param.yaml*** on your **navigation package** (assuming that the package name is *my_robot_2dnav* and that you are using the default global planner NavfnROS) with the following contents:

```
NavfnROS:
  allow_unknown: false
```

And then **load it** when you launch the ***move_base*** node:

```
<launch>
...
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" name="move_base">
    ...
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_2dnav)/base_global_planner_param.yaml" command="load"/>
    ...
  </node>
...
</launch>
```

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on 2014-07-17**:
perfect! the global planning works fine now.